# Below code will delete folders starting with date1.But i want to delete all except date1.So Please help.Thx

Tags: python, operating-system

files=[i for i in os.listdir(src) if (i.startswith(date1) and path.isdir(path.join(src, i)))]

for f in files:
shutil.rmtree(path.join(src,f))

where,src=source path
date1=specific pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it like that. I annotated the code to explain it.

```
dirs = []

# look into your root folder
for item in os.listdir(src):
    # check if item is a directory and matches the pattern
    if(path.isdir(path.join(src, item)) and item.startswith(date1)):
        # remember it
        dirs.append(path.join(src, item))

# go over all remembered directories
for drctry in dirs:
    # look in all sub-directories
    for d, sd, files in os.walk(drctry):
        # go over all files in the directories
        for file in files:
            # check if file still exists to prevent errors
            if(path.isfile(path.join(d, file))):
                # delete it
                os.remove(path.join(d, file))

# go over all remembered directories
for drctry in dirs:
    # delete the tree
    shutil.rmtree(path.join(drctry))
```

I had a test structure like this:

- root folder

  - 2020-04-13
  - 2020-05-22

    - one

      - tst.txt
    - two

      - one

        - testt.rtf
      - test.txt

With my test I deleted the `2020-05-22` with all its content.

Answer (score 0):

Could you elaborate a little more what you're trying to do, please?
Is "date1" the parent folder at which you want to start deleting, or is it also a child folder you want to "spare" from deletion? Or am I totally off here? :)
Maybe you can show an example structure?

Comment: hello Rox,'date1' folder is parent folder which i want to delete,although 'date1' can also have child folders.But i want to delete 'date1' folders so that folders inside it also should be deleted.